# htaccess url rewrite and images and rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Can you see a problem with my htaccess rewrite rules? because it allways matches images so the browser never can get to them

The images are in a folder `images` which is in the root of the web application.

Also the js and css files were redirected badly. This should have been solved by the `!-d` and `!-f` but it seems that it does noting to the url rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^.*mootools.*\.js$ mootools.v1.11.js
RewriteRule ^.*javascript\.js$ javascript.js
RewriteRule ^.*style\.css$ style.css
RewriteRule ^.*slimbox\.css$ slimbox.css
RewriteRule ^.*slimbox\.js$ slimbox.js

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?.html$ ?arg1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: My guess is that it's more a html problem. You probably use relative urls, that no longer work because the urls now contains a 'virtual directory'. Change `<img src="images/test.jpg" />` to `<img src="/images/test.jpg" />`

Comment: yes i do use relative urls in images and other stuff. I'll try your suggestion

Comment: Nope that is not possible to change these because the urls are being generated by a custom made CMS, cound it be somehow achieved that existing files exempt from these rewrite rules?

Comment: yes it is... i bruteforced the urls and came up with this rewrite rule: `RewriteRule ^.*(/images/.*\..{1,4})$ $1`

Comment: Yes, but if a visitor goes to a different page it has to download the same images again, because the url is different. The same goes for your JS and CSS. That is not acceptable in my books, but that's just me.

Comment: I know what you mean, but the underlying CMS system is as bad as it gets also, so this was the quick fix for the problem and at least people can get to the site. Now i can rewrite the url generation routine to be at least a little bit inteligent and not just append strings without any logic.

Comment: If could look into adding a `<base href="http://example.com/" />` into the head.